# Understanding vocabulary size in word2vec

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I am trying to understand word2vec algorithm but some issues makes me really confused. I am using the code from [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py). The issue is that my data size is 184 million words and it contains 2.2 million different words in total. I set the `vocabulary_size` to `250,000`. Does that mean my network actually learns the most frequent 250,000 words and the rest 1.950,000 distinct words are only UNK?

Another issue is that; I understand the model theoretically. However, I am having difficulties to relate it to the code. Does the input layer size correspond to the `vocabulary_size` in the code?

I will be really appreciate if you enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [build_dataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/438604fc885208ee05f9eef2d0f2c630e1360a83/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py#L71) function in the code you'll see that anything above the vocabulary size gets turned into unk, and also how the input layer is set up (only on wrod2vec there are no hidden layers, so that's it).